# Отображение информации только на отображаемый слайдер

Tags: jquery, html, slider, hide

Добрый день.

Есть слайдер подключаемый в виде плагина на jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/falkone/a01cjuem/ 
На каждом слайде есть свое описание и кнопка(условно). Как можно задать отображение данных элементов только на отображаемом слайдере в данный момент и скрывать на неактивных в данный момент картинках, с помощью jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй псевдо-селектор `$(":visible" )`.

https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/